# django，How to tag people on Facebook photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api

App can't use Facebook's tag people function.
Here is the code.

```
def upload_caption(self, caption, location=None, link=''):
    media_data = self.page_api.put_object(self.publisher.original_social_uid,
                                              'feed',
                                              message=caption,
                                              link=link,
                                              tags=usertags,
                                              published=True)
```

Here is usertags.

```
[{
   tag_uid:122,
   x:0.45656,
   y:0.45656,
},]
```

The following also tried.(tags)

```
[{
   created_time:datetime,
   tagging_user:user,
   x:0.4556,
   y:0.4556
},]
```

Comment: did those users authorize your app? what is the debug info? (the response from the api) did you check out the api reference to make sure it should work?

Comment: I can send picture updates normally,Just can't tag people.

Comment: you did not answer a single question from my comment...

Comment: Does tag people require special certification? Only authenticated to send content. 
I want to ask the parameters passed in above. Can you tell me?